# How to figure out which exception a function may throw?

Tags: clojure

For example, for `slurp`, I checked both http://clojure.org/api/api and clojuredoc. Neither says what kind of exception this function may throw.

Of course, for `slurp`, I know it will throw exception sometimes so I can just try to catch all, but for an unfamiliar function, how can I figure out whether it may or may not throw exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was my workflow to see what exception type could be thrown for slurp

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/slurp

> Opens a reader on f and reads all its contents, returning a string.
>   See clojure.java.io/reader for a complete list of supported
>   arguments.

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.java.io/reader

> Attempts to coerce its argument into an open java.io.Reader.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html

here we see that java.io.Reader throws IOException
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/IOException.html

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.